# Decoding Void with Swift 4’s Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have a generic REST request:

```
struct Request<T> {…}
```

The `T` is the return type of the request, for example:

```
struct Animal {…}
let animalRequest = Request<Animal>
let animal: Animal = sendRequest(animalRequest)
```

Now I would like to express that the generic type has to conform to `Decodable` so that I can decode the JSON response from the server:

```
struct Request<T> where T: Decodable {…}
struct Animal: Decodable {…}
```

This makes sense and works – until I arrive at a request that has no response, a `Request<Void>`. The compiler is not happy about that one:

```
Type 'Void' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

My mischevious attempt to solve this by adding the `Decodable` conformance to `Void` was quickly found out by the compiler:

```
extension Void: Decodable {…} // Error: Non-nominal type 'Void' cannot be extended
```

It feels right to have the request generic over the return type. Is there a way to make it work with `Void` return types? (For example the requests that just create something on the server and don’t return anything.)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question but it's up to you – the developer – to take care of  *a**void**ing* the `Void` requests

Comment: I can understand your point of view, but at the same time it feels right that if a thing is generic over _x_, then `Void` aka zero tuple `()` should be a valid value for _x_. After all it’s trivially `Equatable` and `Decodable`.

Comment: @zoul Still have to wonder what `Request<Void>` is supposed to mean. Why are you using things like that? If that's a response type, it is never `Void`. It can be empty but it's never `Void`.

Comment: What’s the difference between empty and `Void`? To me, there’s a perfect analogy in plain functions, a request returning `Void` is the same as a function returning `Void`. Both are only used for the side effects.

Answer (score 42):

A simple workaround is to introduce a custom “no-reply” type that would replace `Void`:

```
struct NoReply: Decodable {}
```

Conforming `Void` to `Decodable` is not possible. `Void` is just a type alias for an empty tuple, `()`, and tuples cannot conform to protocols at this moment, but they will, eventually.

Comment: This solution is fine

Comment: amazing. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a DecodingError.dataCorrupted with context: `Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}))`

Comment: @Marmoy perhaps you're trying to decode an empty Data. JSONDecoder requires the input data to be a valid JSON document.
As a workaround you can detect if the response data is empty and in that case replace it with a mocked empty json data:
`let emptyJson = "{}".data(using: .utf8)`

Answer (score 1):

I found that sometimes other encoded objects of another types can be decoded to NoReply.self. For example custom Error type (enum) can be.

Playground example of this case:

```
enum MyError: String, Codable {
    case general
}

let voidInstance = VoidResult()
let errorInstance = MyError.general
let data1 = try! JSONEncoder().encode(voidInstance)
let data2 = try! JSONEncoder().encode(errorInstance)

let voidInstanceDecoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(VoidResult.self, from: data1)
//VoidResult as expected

let errorInstanceDecoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyError.self, from: data2)
//MyError.general as expected

let voidInstanceDecodedFromError = try! JSONDecoder().decode(VoidResult.self, from: data2)
//VoidResult - NOT EXPECTED

let errorInstanceDecodedFromVoid = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ScreenError.self, from: data1)
//DecodingError.typeMismatch - Expected
```

So my suggestion is to add "uniqueness to NoReply (zoul's answer)):

```
struct VoidResult: Codable {
    var id = UUID()
}

let voidInstanceDecodedFromError = try! JSONDecoder().decode(VoidResult.self, from: data2)
//DecodingError.typeMismatch - Now its fine - as expected
```